# How to read/write int in Parcelable object?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

My int variables are not reading/writing correctly in my Parcelable object.
I am passing my object from one activity to another but the int variables are not the same once I pass it and read it.

Heres my code.

PARCELABLE OBJECT:

```
class someObject implements Parcelable
int something;
int something2;

//normal constructor
... 

public someObject(Parcel in){
  this.something = in.readInt();
  this.something2 = in.readInt();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
   dest.writeInt(something);
   dest.writeInt(something2);
}
//creator and other parcel stuff
...

//mutators for int variables
...
```

How I passed it in activity1:

```
//instantiate someObject 
...
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtras("stuff", someObject);
```

Passed to activity2:

```
onCreate(Bundle blah){
Bundle b = getIntent.getExtras();
someObject some = b.getParcelable("stuff");

}
```

I output something and something2 within the constructor and the activity that I pass it too. They are different values, what did I do wrong?

I have other String member variables in my parcelable object class and they seem to work. Just the 2 ints are not working properly.

Comment: You mean that `something` is different when you create a new `someObject`, and when you receive that object in your `activity2#onCreate()` method?  Not that `something` is different from `something2`, right?

Comment: Exactly, I pass something and something2 into the original constructor in activity1 then try to retrieve it in activity2. But something in activity1 != something in activity2. Same for something2

Comment: The code you show looks fine to me.  Perhaps there's something elsewhere that's messing things up?  It's really easy to get cut-and-paste errors when you have things named like `something` and `something2`.  Maybe a *fat-finger* error?

Comment: Also, I can already see that you made one error when copying your code into your question above.  There is no method `intent.putExtras("stuff", someObject)`.  There is `intent#putExtras(Bundle)` or `intent#putExtra(String, Parcelable)`.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

```
final int    readInt()
```

> Read an integer value from the parcel at the current dataPosition().

The current dataPosition() means that the two in.readInt() are different.

(Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html)

Comment: How would I pass the int then?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but if you want the same int, do: this.something = in.readInt(); this.something2 = this.something; I suggest to edit the post and add more datails...

Comment: Your dataposition() input helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, my write and read were not in the same position so the dataPosition() was off and thus reading different objects.

Ex)

```
 read(parcel in){
   in.readString(); //1
   in.readString(); //2
   in.readInt();    //3
}

 write(Parcel dest, int flag){
   dest.writeString(); //1
   dest.writeInt();    //3
   dest.writeString(); //2
}
```

Comment: That's why you shouldn't post questions with code that isn't actually the code you're using, and having problems with.